# Can Sprint Planning and Review be combined?

Tags: agile, scrum, jira-agile, sprint

Nowadays I am learning about agile process. I am learning all the agile stuff. I was talking to one of my friends and He asked me, can we have both sprint review and planning together. I was speechless when he asked me. Can any one tell me whether it is good to have them together or not?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The participants in the sprint review are the development team, the Product Owner, the Scrum Master and the stakeholders. The participants in the planning meeting are the development team, the Product Owner and the Scrum Master.

So it would be possible to have the meetings back-to-back, letting the stakeholders leave before planning started. However, most teams would have the sprint retrospective *between* the sprint review and the planning session.

With small teams I have sometimes booked out 2 hours of meeting rooms and run sprint review, retrospective and then planning back-to-back (with short breaks of course). Some teams like this approach as they get all of the meetings out of the way in one block.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean in the same meeting, sure, but it doesn't really make sense to combine them in any way - they are two completely separate "disciplines".

I think in the settings I've been in, if you did combine them there would be a tendency to lower the priority on the sprint review relative to the planning process, and that's not a good thing - sprint reviews are important tools in adjusting how the entire sprint process is handled.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend you to have it together because they are completely different, i.e. Sprint Review is used to present the stakeholders what your team did during the last sprint, this meeting has focus on the end user where the team is going to be fed by end user's feedback, the Product Owner need to be involved in the meeting, I mean instead of the team presenting the status to PO and the stakeholders, PO should be the voice of the team, PO needs to take the front and present what the team have done to the stakeholders.

Different from Sprint Review, on Sprint Planning the stakeholders are not required in the meeting, the planning is focused in the team itself, this meeting will define the next steps in the project. Taking the time to plan allows the team to review the work about to be undertaken, estimate the effort required to complete that work, and then commit to a prioritized list of stories and tasks that are within the team’s calculated capacity.

So in a nutshell, these ceremonies have different purposes and I would not recommend you to merge both.